# Quicksort (JAVA)

Tags: quicksort

Lets say you have an array of size `n` with randomly generated elements and you want to use quicksort to sort the array. For large enough n (say 1,000,000), in order to speed up quicksort, it would make sense to stop recursing when the array gets small enough, and use insertion sort instead. In such an implementation, the base case for Quicksort is some value `base > 1`. What would the optimal base value to choose and why?

Comment: That looks like a word-for-word copy of a homework assignment.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in the answer - what a shame.

Comment: @CD Sanchez: the article I linked has ballpark numbers for when to switch from quick to insertion sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the time complexity of quicksort (average and worst case) and the time complexity of other sort that might do better for small n.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) - it has good starting info about comparing the two algorithms.  When you have a more specific question, feel free to come back.